# how assign custom created format in proc format

Tags: sas

This one is a hard one I have the this format which I have created .

This is my custom format

```
data work.myBins;
    do start = -2.5 to 2.45 by 0.05;
        end=start+0.05;
        label=catx(' ',put(start,8.2),'to',put(end,8.2));
    output;
    end;
run;
proc format cntlin=work.myBins; run;
```

Now I have further created this format using proc format

```
  proc format;
    value customFormat 
                    2.5-high='Higher then 2.5'
                    low-2.5='Lower then -2.5'
                    other=bin.;


run;
```

Will this work

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 extra records in your myBins dataset, one for the 'low - <2.5' range, and another for the '2.5 - high' range. Then use the single format to cover all values.